# Where is the postfix Mail Delivery Status Report?

Tags: centos, logs, postfix

I'm using CentOS 7.  I wanted to test my PostFix mail forwarding so I ran

```
[root@server /]# echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v admin@mydomein.com
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>.
```

I don't see the email received at my forwarding address and I can't figure out where the log of what happened is.  I checked

```
[root@server /]# ls -al /var/log/maillog
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Mar  6 09:48 /var/log/maillog
```

But that log file is empty.  How do I find out where things went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The message you posted says the `Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>`.

I would check the root user's mail which by default should be `/var/spool/mail/root`.

Answer (score 3):

I found it helpful to use sendmail with `-f` option, like so:

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -f errors.here@example.com -v admin@mydomein.com
```

`-f` sets the envelope sender address. This is the address where delivery problems are sent to.

Comment: This at least generated an email to the error address. Although the email has no content, so it didn't help me identify why sendmail doesn't send a message to the desired test address. Any suggestions?

Comment: @inspirednz It should actually come with an error message. Did you check the message headers?